# Do I need a ETL?

Tags: etl

We currently use Datastage ETL to - Export a CSV/text file with data from 15 tables(3 different schemas) on a daily basis.

I am wondering If there is a simpler way to accomplish this with out using an ETL. I tried Scriptella. It looks simple/fast, but it again it is an ETL. Please suggest..

Comment: I think asking "do I need an ETL *tool*?" is the more appropriate question.  Just asking "do I need an ETL?" is like asking "do I need to move data from one place to another?" - and the answer to that will depend on what project you're working on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We use Python.  Every programming language -- every single one ever invented -- is an alternative to an ETL.

You never **need** an ETL.

The questions is these:

- Which is cheaper to build?  Custom software or a configuration of an ETL?
- Which is cheaper to maintain an operate?
- Which is easier to adapt to changing requirements?

Comment: @ S.Lott - Thanks for your reply. As I said since we want to get rid of ETL, we are thinking of doing something light weight and quick e.g. ruby/java(not light weight though), so that current developers can write/maintain the code (and we don't need to staff an ETL guy). We don't have Python expertise currently. We used java for similar tasks before, but we would like to know how others have solved the same problem.

Comment: @pingu - We use perl. You should get some experience at some sort of so-called "scripting language". This sort of thing is trivial.

Comment: @pingu: "we would like to know how others have solved the same problem".  I said Python.  What more do you want to know?

Comment: Today I have gone through the ETL work done in our company.I earlier thought there would be lot of stuff in an ETL e.g. ORM to improve performance, but it looked pretty straight forward, with some UI(who cares), nothing complex as you guys said. I felt all that could have been easily done using Java and Ant(or any language as Lott pointed out).Thanks both of you.

Comment: @pingu: ORM's don't improve performance. That's not their purpose. Same for ETL tools. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198/what-etl-tool-do-you-use

Comment: @S.Lott +1 I was searching for similar case. e.g. suitable ETL processess to load MS Access DB with `.csv, .txt, Excel files`.

Comment: If your program is extracting data, transforming it and then loading it somewhere: That's called an ETL! Any little script you do is an ETL. You always need an ETL Program.

Comment: [There a proposal for a dedicated Q&A site for Business Intelligence. Follow, Post and Support to get it up.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a free and easy to use ETL tool such as expressor Studio.  You can download it at http://www.expressorstudio.com.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents.

Datastage is an awful tool, and expensive to license.

SSIS is much simpler, or cloverETL is good.

ETL tool vs code is a good question.

ETL tools often have better performance as can queue data up ready to be used
where programming is is going to do this one at a time, and datastage can do this in parallel (but again i think it blows). PLus ETL tools can get data from multiple heterogeneous sources, where as you cant do this (easily) with code.

However if any data transformations etc are all to be done with data on the same server, I generally end up doing as much in SQL/TSQL(or PL/SQL) as possible, as it is just tonnes easier to debug/maintain. Primary Keys/Foreign Keys are your friend, and any missed lookups can be checked through checking counts later on to ensure data integrity is in order.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a ETL tool for that purpose. You can perform all the tasks using python, right from extracting data from CSVs/XMLs/text files, transforming data (identifying data types, null value transformation) and loading into tables.
https://towardsdatascience.com/python-etl-tools-best-8-options-5ef731e70b49

Comment: I think they probably found a solution already after asking this 9 years and 9 months ago.

Comment: I am presently working on ETL, I thought the resource which I used might help others, so I have presented my thought.

Comment: I understand but you posted a link. The link might disappear in the future, then the information is lost. And you could have posted an example with some code or a little bit more consise information. Furthermore, there is already an answer that is recommending Python that was accepted and received 11 upvotes. Your answer does not add more significant information.

Answer (score 0):

ETL can definitely be performed without the help of ETL Tools.
for eg: we can develop python scripts or there is open sources like Drift to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use a cheap ETL tool for your task. Because ETL tools work better than code always and make your task easy.
[ETL Tool Vs Manual Script](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/is-manual-etl-better-than-no-code-etl-are-etl-tools-dead/)

> “According to the IT research firm Forrester, the low-code development
> platform market will reach a value of $21.2 billion by 2022, growing
> at an annual rate of 40 percent. What’s more, 45 percent of developers
> have already used a low-code platform or expect to do so in the near
> future.”