# Tools to assist with complex XML creation such as DDEX?

Tags: xml, etl, ddex

DDEX is a standard for data exchange in the music industry
(http://www.ddex.net/)

It's a fairly complex XML standard or set of standards which involve creating hierarchical XML.

Are there any (opensource) tools to assist with doing this? Our data is already in a database, so some sort of ETL or reporting solution to create the file maybe?

We currently use Pentaho / Kettle / PDI - But i'm not sure this is necessarily the right tool in this case.

Comment: To assist with the XML specifically, or the whole ETL stack. I'd give the same answer as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099974/do-i-need-a-etl/5099998#5099998 (Perl/Python/etc.), but you're probably best off with what you know.

Comment: I've come across E4X - looks like a useful Javascript library for working with XML. I think this will do what I want (http://wso2.org/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html#constructing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we stuck with what we knew, and we implemented DSR reporting for DDEX in Kettle.
Turns out the XML processing is fine, we did a bit of bodging with shell scripts but in hindsight there is a very powerful xml join step we could have used to do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

DDEX is making some open source tools available to the DDEX community here:

https://github.com/ddexnet

I don't think that there's anything that directly helps with DSR right now, but hopefully something may appear in the future....