# R vs Pentaho Spoon as an ETL tool

Tags: r, pentaho

Background (sorry it's so long):

I've been tasked with maintaining an ETL that collects a variety of online advertising data, around 20-30 MBs a day, and appends it to tables in MySQL.  Outside contractors built the ETL with Pentaho Spoon (kitchen, kettle?).  The ETL consists of about 250 jobs and transformations (.ktr,.kjb), each with about 5 to 25 steps.  It is very common that something is going wrong in this large process.  I've found that writing R scripts to do the transform and load is much more efficient.  In fact, I think the ETL could be reduced to well under 1000 lines of code besides calls with RMySQL (i.e. plyr!).  Perhaps Python would be used to extract the data from the web.

My use of R has led to some resistance.  The computer programmers that designed the ETL don't know R so couldn't be called if I leave, and moreover a lot of time was invested in the Spoon ETL.  Also, a layman can more easily follow the steps visually in Spoon, than in the R scripts.  For my part, I think we are getting bogged down by the ETL.  However, I don't have a large say in the matter as I don't have a background in computer science.

Please comment if you have any insights on the following.  Please know I have been researching this for months and have read many opinions, but nothing as concise or reliable as SO usually provides:

1. R has been called not as scalable by some at the company.  I think the opposite mostly because of the logging capabilities.  Spoon has limited pure logging output, whereas all R scripts can be sinked into a daily log.  Fixing and avoiding mistakes in the .ktrs is very tedious, but easy with setting flags and/or searching through the R log.  Any thoughts on this?
2. This leads to a big picture question.  What is the point of ETLs like Pentaho?  This post [Do I need a ETL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099974/do-i-need-a-etl?rq=1), leads me to believe that if you use R or other so-called OOL, there is no reason to have a tool like Pentaho.  Can someone please confirm this if so?  I really need a second opinion here.  If this is so who uses tools like Pentaho?  Is it simply people without the programming background, or someone else?  I do see a fair amount of Pentaho questions on SO.
3. It is true that a lot more people use R and than Pentaho, right?  This http://www.kdnuggets.com/2012/05/top-analytics-data-mining-big-data-software.html makes it look so.  To be honest I was surprised that Pentaho was 5th, which makes me doubly wonder who uses Pentaho and if my doubts about it's use in my work setting are misplaced.

Thanks for any responses.  I don't mean any condescension towards Spoon or Spoon users; I am just really confused and in need of outside opinions.

Comment: Suggest to ask this question further on quora then - that seems to be a better place for subjective discussion/debate.  I think it's a great topic and well worth debating somewhere.

Comment: Interesting I'm not the only one thinking about this:  The BARUG wants to focus a meetup on it.  http://www.meetup.com/R-Users/events/47885552/?a=md1_evn&rv=md1&_af_eid=47885552&_af=event.  FWIW, I quit this job after just 1 year because the inefficiency was driving me insane.  Happily and I think effectively using R in a startup environment now.

Comment: I already use data.table for ETL processes in R, it's syntax is friendly and each brackets DT[,] can be compared to transformation block in terms of ETL.
Regarding question 1. you can make a logging process to log anything you would like: transformation time, processed nrow, catched error message. Just drop the log_dt (data.table/data.frame object) to the dbWriteTable.

Comment: all in all a great question. Was this ever asked in Quora?

Answer (score 4):

R as an ETL tool? Thats a new one, but whatever floats your boat.

I would say this though, if you can get 250 jobs and transformations down to under 1000 lines of R I would say your ETL is poorly written.

Along with this you have to think about supportability and scalability. Both of which I would imagine would be far easier with a graphical tool like Spoon rather than R code.

Personally I think you are misguided and the question you ask is poorly written but thats a different argument.

Regarding your points, PDI's logging is very good and you can log pretty much however you like, all into one large database table if you like a consolidated log.

ETL's wont be going away, even with the advent of the love of unstructured data storage pools like HDFS, also think about data analysis done outside R, if you want reporting or OLAP over the top of your data, it will still need transforming regardless.

Is it true, more people use R vs Pentaho? What sort of question is that? By Pentaho I assume you mean PDI? How can that ever be compared? A data analysis tool vs ETL tool and you want to count users? eh? If on the other hand you mean R vs Pentaho as a whole, then I would guess no.You are looking at a report on R vs Weka and making it fit your ETL argument. That doesn't wash in a month of sundays.

==EDIT==
Okay so you have around 1000 lines of R & Python code currently. As your bosses requirements expand this slowly grows over time, and because you are trying to hit deadlines the new code is written as cleanly or as well documented as the code you currently have in place. So over time this grows to 5000 lines say plus a few python scripts. Then one day you get hit by a bus, and some new person has to come in and manage your code... where do they start, how to they make changes?

Virtually anyone with a modicum of data experience could make a change to a PDI ETL should they be required to. Where as it would take some with enough in depth R knowledge to make changes to what you have done.

ETL tools are designed to be quick and easy to use, they also offer far more than R can provide in terms of data connectivity to different systems (non db or file based, for example), although I guess this is why people resort to python etc.
That said there is room for both, there is an R plugin for PDI kicking around in the community I've seen demonstrated.

On top of that I've seen enough TSQL to ETL migrations over the years to know from experience, that even though maintaining your ETL in code may seem practical in the short term, in the long term it just brings more pain.

On the other hand if you can code 250 PDI transformations down to 1000 lines of R, your ETL is likely bloated through bad design by your predecessor.

If you'd like me to give an opinion on your existing PDI ETL structure, that can also be arranged.

Tom

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tom.  I knew my question wasn't written well, even with weeks of crafting it in my head.  You are absolutely right that I am misguided - I have no clue what I am doing!  The point here is that this is my first job.  I know how to use R.  I've never used an ETL tool.  It appears R does what the ETL tool is supposed to be doing, plus the data analysis of course.  Please describe why the phrase 'R as an ETL tool' is crazy.  Even with all my research, I do not know what the heck an ETL tool is versus a mix of R and Python.  Please advise if more info is needed.

Comment: I'll edit my answer....

Comment: I agree that lack of documentation in ETL tools is not so painful as lack of doc in R, but yet doing it in R you will have more time to write better doc, better debugging capabilities, easier change request development. You can organize your code into well documented packages, have a good versioning, also easily switch repositories between DEV/QA/PROD.